# I deployed GCP deeplearning vm but could not deploy due to a 400 error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kaggle

I am Japanese, so I am converting Japanese into English by machine translation. Sorry for my poor English.
Before deploying the Deep Leaning VM,
1.created a VPC network,
2.created firewall rules, and
3.created a NAT configuration using Cloud Router.
After deploying, the following error occurred and I could not deploy.
Please let me know how to resolve the error.

error-message
kaggle-gpu-vm: {"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/common-cu110-v20230315-debian-10'. The referenced image resource cannot be found.","reason":"invalid"}],"message":"Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceImage': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/common-cu110-v20230315-debian-10'. The referenced image resource cannot be found.","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/for-kaggle-384012/zones/us-west1-b/instances","httpMethod":"POST"}}

The deep leaning vm is
Set instance name kaggle-gpu.
Zone is set to us-west-1b
For Machine Type, set the GPU type to NVIDIA T4, number of GPUs to 1, and n1-highmen-2
For Framework, set to Intel(R) optimized Base (with Intel(R) MKL and CUDA 11.0).
GPU is set to ON.
For Networking, the VPC network and subnetwork created in step 1 were specified, and the external IP was set to "None".

1. Creation of VPC network,
   　Region is set to us-west-1,
   　IP address range was set to "192.168.1.0/24",
   　The network name is set to private-network.
2. For the creation of firewall rules
   　Set the network name to private-network created earlier,
   　Set the traffic direction to upstream,
   　Allow action on match,
   　target to all instances on the network,
   　Set the IP address range to "35.235.240.0/20" to allow access only via Cloud IAP,
   　Checked "TCP" for protocol and port, and specified port "22".
3. For the NAT configuration using Cloud Router
   　Specify the VPC network you just created as the network,
   　Set the region to us-west-1
   　Cloud RouterA new Cloud-router was created and specified.

Comment: The problem is `The referenced image resource cannot be found`. That means the image used to create and launch the VM does not exist. You will need to open a support ticket with Google Support or file a bug report.